# classification of groups of order $4p, p\ge 5$, need help finding automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, semidirect-product

So I've been working on this problem for my qual prep class, and I have it all down except for one detail.    I'm doing it by semidirect products, and with the Sylow $p$ group normal,  choosing the case when the Sylow 2 subgroup is cyclic.

It's in the special case when the prime is congruent to $1$, mod $4$.   Then we get an extra subgroup,  as there's an extra automorphism of order 4.   My problem is....how do I find this automorphism?  I'd know it'd be the generator of the group to the $\frac {p-1} 4$ power,  but I was looking online and there didn't seem to be a general formula for finding a generator of a multiplicative group of the finite field of order $p$.  So...is there another way of specifying this automorphism of order 4 in the group of automorphisms of Cyclic groups of prime order who are congruent to 1 mod 4?

Or am I stuck just saying "Pick that element!"

Comment: As far as I know, there is no general formula for finding a generator of the multiplicative group $\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$ in terms of $n$. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n#Finding_primitive_roots

Comment: Do you mean an explicit exression for elements of order 4?

Comment: Yes, an explicit solution. Thanks, I had to go run and teach.  And yes, I saw that in my research. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p \equiv 1$ mod $4$, $p=1+4m$ then $(p-1)! \equiv -1$ mod $4$, (Wilson). Hence $(2m)!\prod\limits_{i=0}^{2m-1+}(2m+1+i) \equiv -1$, now $4m+1 \equiv 0$ so $2m+1 \equiv -2m$, hence $(2m)!\prod\limits_{i=0}^{2m-1+}(-2m+i) \equiv -1$, so $(2m)!\prod\limits_{i=0}^{2m-1+}(-1)(2m-i) \equiv -1$ therefore $(2m)!(-1)^{2m}\prod\limits_{i=0}^{2m-1}(2m-i) \equiv -1$, hence $[(2m)!]^{2} \equiv -1$, so this tells you that the class $m$ of $(\frac{p-1}{2})!$ has order $4$. Now, multiplication by $m$ is an automorphism of order 4. $(-m)$ is the other element of order 4, and both are the unique ones, as $x^{4}=1$ has $4$ solutions, two of which are $1$ and $-1$.